# Does FetchXML have a way to randomly order records?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I am looking for a functionality that will display records in random order with FetchXML. Essentially the SQL equivalent of

```
order by newid()
```

Comment: Do you need the sequence of retrieved records to be different every time? Or is it acceptable to simply have an arbitrary sequence (and not the "natural" sequence that would normally be provided, which is their order on physical storage). If "arbitrary" is good enough, you could create a field that is given a random number on create and sort by that, but you'd get the same sequence every time.

Comment: How many records do you need? Do you need a single random record, or a "sample" of N records chosen arbitrarily?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

You cannot "inject" functions in the queries.

You could order by the id column, but in many cases it is not really random anyway.

Comment: In fact, not random by design. Using a Random GUID causes the index to need rebuilding a lot; Microsoft's unique-but-also-kinda-sequential approach gives you "blocks" of GUIDs, which means large numbers of inserts will end up near each other physically on the disk.